# Ionic navbar dropdown-menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, ionic-framework, navbar

I'd like to have an icon (three-bars) on the right-side in the navbar.

Something like this:

[image]

I used to have it, I found the code somewhere on the internet, but I lost my code and I couldn't find again the URL from which I learned the technique.

Please help me recover the technique.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case (according to information that you provided  in the comment to my previous answer) you have to use [$ionicPopover](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopover/) .

You can read some extra information about this feature in the next article - [Popover Support Lands in Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/popover-support-landed/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I get correct, you want to use [side menu](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/).

[image]

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <!-- Left menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  </ion-side-menu>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <!-- Right menu -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right">
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

function ContentController($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
}
```

Check out detailed example by link that I provided above.

Comment: Hi Rredcat, thanks for the answer. It also crossed my mind, but my users don't want side menu. They want dropdown (on the right). (we already side menu on the left for other uses).